# MPMoviePlayerController does not respond to setFullscreen = NO

Tags: iphone, ipad, mpmovieplayercontroller

I'm creating a custom MovieController using MPMovieController as base. I can switch the video to full-screen by calling

```
_[moviePlayer setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];_
```

Calling the same function (*[moviePlayer setFullscreen:NO animated:YES];*) to bring the movie-player back to the original state (ie when user press Done button) does not work.

As an alternative, I've also tried to -

a) listening to **MPMoviePlayerDidExitFullscreenNotification** and calling *moviePlayBackDidFinish:* function as a result of this.

b) posting my **custom notification** from inside "Done" function using this -

```
NSDictionary *thisDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:MPMovieFinishReasonUserExited] forKey:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishReasonUserInfoKey];  
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:MPMoviePlayerDidExitFullscreenNotification object:moviePlayer userInfo:thisDictionary];
```

But in all these cases, the movie-player view does not come back to its original state.

Help Please.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to register notification for the event. When you prepare for to play the video, do like this

```
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                        selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:) 
                        name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification 
                        object:nil];
```

and in your moviePlayBackDidFinish selector, do like this

```
  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification 
        object:nil];


[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```